# Send Password Reset Email through different Guards

Tags: php, laravel, broker, include-guards, reset-password

I have 4 different guards registered in my `auth.php` file. I have a single page for resetting the password for users in the four guards. So, while sending the email I manage to figure out which guard to use by sending it through the form.

My `ForgotPasswordController.php`

```
protected function guard()
{
    return Auth::guard(Input::get('guard'));
}

protected function broker()
{
    if (Input::get('guard') == 'web') {
        return Password::broker('users');
    }
    return Password::broker(Input::get('guard'));
}
```

But in the `ResetPasswordController.php` file, I am not able to do the same logic. How can I get the same guard and broker used here in that file? Can I store the guard name in the database along with the password resets token? If yes, How? Please guide me